# Show XML tag full path with php

Tags: php, xml

Let's assume we want to process this Feed: http://tools.forestview.eu/xmlp/xml_feed.php?aid=1094&cid=1000

I'm trying to show the nodes of an XML file this way:

```
deals->deal->dealsite
deals->deal->deal_id
deals->deal->deal_title
```

This is in order to be able to process feeds that we don't know what their XML tags are. So we will let the user choose that deals->deal->deal_title is the Deal Title and will recognize it that way.

I have been trying ages to do this with this code:

```
    class HandleXML {
    var $root_tag = false;
    var $xml_tags = array();
    var $keys = array();

function parse_recursive(SimpleXMLElement $element)
{
        $get_name = $element->getName();
        $children   = $element->children();     // get all children

        if (empty($this->root_tag)) {
            $this->root_tag = $this->root_tag.$get_name;
        }

        $this->xml_tags[] = $get_name;

        // only show children if there are any
        if(count($children))
        {
               foreach($children as $child)
               {
                $this->parse_recursive($child); // recursion :)
               }
        }
        else {
            $key = implode('-&gt;', $this->xml_tags);
            $this->xml_tags = array();
            if (!in_array($key, $this->keys)) {
                if (!strstr('&gt;', $key) && count($this->keys) > 0) { $key = $this->root_tag.'-&gt;'.$key; }
                if (!in_array($key, $this->keys)) {
                    $this->keys[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($feed_url, null, true);
$handle_xml = new HandleXML;

$handle_xml->parse_recursive($xml);
foreach($handle_xml->keys as $key) {
    echo $key.'<br />';
}
exit;
```

but here's what I get instead:

```
deals->deal->dealsite
deals->deal_id
deals->deal_title
```

See on 2nd and 3rd line the **deal->** part is missing.

I have also tried with this code: http://pastebin.com/FkPWXF64 but it's definitely not the best way to go and it doesn't always work.

No matter how many times I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my sites I use a little different approach to handle xml feed. In your case it would look like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://tools.forestview.eu/xmlp/xml_feed.php?aid=1094&cid=1000");

foreach($xml->{'deal'} as $deal) 
{
$dealsite = $deal->{'dealsite'};
$dael_id = $deal->{'dael_id'};
$deal_title = $deal->{'deal_title'};
$deal_url = $deal->{'deal_url'};
$deal_city = $deal->{'deal_city'};
$deal_category = $deal->{'deal_category'};

// and so on for the rest

// do some stuff with the variables like insert into MySQL

}
```

Comment: Well the thing is that in my case I don't know the XML tags and this level is the recognition of the tags. The user has to tell the script what each tag is for.